# Find and replace a string separated by delimiter

Tags: linux, vim, vi

How can i find and replace a string like "aa:bb:cc:dd" with "ring12" when using vi in linux? For normal strings without delimiter, i know it as

```
%s/randomstring/ring12/g
```

But how to deal with string having ':' symbol? I know i should use backslash '\' but don't know the syntax.

Comment: A simple `:h :s` (or `:h pattern`) would have already answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually it doesn't require a \ ... you can simply use something like this:

> *<ESC>*:**%s**,aa:bb:cc:dd,ring12,g

Where *`<ESC>`* is the escape key to put vi in command mode.